# Firebase Auth only for devices using my app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a question about Firebase Auth.
I'm working on my app and, even if I downloaded Firebase Auth Protocol using Pods, I realized that I really don't need them.

The aim of my app is to show some random quote about users but I don't need to Auth them 'cause I don't want and I don't need to implement an Auth system.

In few words: if you're using my app, you can submit a random quote anonymously.

How do I have to set the Authentication from Firebase Dashboard in order to allow ONLY the users who use my app to do that? How can I prevent people not to submit info if they're not using an iOS device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the user [sign in anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) and have a rule in Firebase that you have to be signed in to post quotes. If you also have to be signed in to read the quotes the rules would look like this.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this through anonymous authentication is a good first step, but the rules in Casper's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47268879) are quite easy to bypass. If you don't have a better authorization schema for your users, I recommend implementing the newly introduced [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) to ensure requests are only allowed from apps that are registered in your Firebase project.